# Programmatically start an OSGi folder bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

I've created a OSGi Bundle Project in Eclipse and I want to start it programmatically from another Java Project.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
Map<String,String> config = new HashMap<String,String>();
Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
framework.start();
BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
Bundle bundle = context.installBundle("file:./test.ServiceA");
bundle.start();
```

but I have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error loading bundle activator.
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.servicea.Activator cannot be found by test.ServiceA_1.0.0.qualifier
```

everything works if I install the plugin jar instead of point to the folder

```
Bundle bundle = context.installBundle("file:./tmp/test.ServiceA_1.0.0.201504172035.jar");
```

but I would like to debug directly the Eclipse project folder.

Anyone is able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Put "reference:" to the beginning of the URL. By doing that

- The content of the bundle will not be copied to the working (or cache) folder of the OSGi container but it will be used from its original location
- Folders can be installed as OSGi bundles

This is not part of the specification but works in Equinox and Felix (and probably in Knopflerfish as well)

Based on your example:

```
Bundle bundle = context.installBundle("reference:file:./test.ServiceA");
```

**Edit based on comments**

As the MANIFEST.MF file is in *./test.ServiceA* but the compiled classes are under *./test.serviceA/bin*, the *"Bundle-Classpath: bin"* MANIFEST header must be provided temporary until the bundle is installed from the folder. Before the release, the header must be removed as the classes will be in the root of the generated JAR.

Comment: It doesn't work, it continues to return me the same error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.servicea.Activator cannot be found by test.ServiceA_1.0.0.qualifier`

Comment: Does ./test.serviceA/test/servicea/Activator.class exist? Could you please try installing your bundle using an absolute path?

Comment: Eclipse puts all classes under the `./test.serviceA/bin/...` folder.

Comment: Than the correct url is "reference:file:./test.serviceA/bin/". I guess META-INF folder is under bin as well.

Comment: No `META-INF` is under `./test.serviceA/`

Comment: In that case the only chance is if you add "Bundle-Classpath" MANIFEST header to your bundle temporary and tell that the classes are in the bin folder of the bundle. Before the release, you must remove this header as in that case your jar will not work. WABs use the same technique to tell that classes are under WEB-INF/classes. More info: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-ClassPath

Comment: WABs are WARs packaged as OSGi bundles. I said that as an example where Bundle-Classpath manifest header is used. You should try adding "Bundle-Classpath: bin".